# How do I make another array a subitem of another array？

Tags: javascript

I have the following code：

```
var a = [
  {id:16, name:"product",productCount:1},
  {id:17, name:"clothes",productCount:1},
]

var b = [
  {id:1, parentId:16, name:"phone"},
  {id:2, parentId:17, name:"coat"},
  {id:3, parentId:16, name:"mac"},
  {id:4, parentId:16, name:"apple"},
]
```

I tried the following:

According to the condition,Let `b` be a subarray of `a`

```
let result = []
a.forEach( ( item ,index)=>{
  if(b[index].parentId === item.id){
    result.push(item);
    result[index].childAs=[];
    result[index].childAs.push(b[index]);
  }
})
```

I don't get what I want,

I expect results:

```
var a = [
  {id:16, name:"product",productCount:1, childAs:[
    {id:1, parentId:16, name:"phone"},
    {id:3 ,parentId:16, name:"mac"},
    {id:4, parentId:16, name:"apple"},
   ]
},
  {id:17, name:"clothes",productCount:1, childAs:[{id:2, parentId:17, name:"coat"}]}
]
```

---

**Update desired results:**

What should I do if I change the result to this?

```
var result = 
[
 {label:'a name value',value:"a id value",
 children:[{label:"b name value",value:"b parentId value"}]
 },
 ...
]
```

Can you help me?

Comment: `result[index].childAs=[];` will empty the array over and over again. You only need that line if `result[index].childAs` doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `forEach` with `find` - for each item in `b`, check if the `parentId` exists as an `id` in `a`. If there's an item check if there's a children prop. If there is, push the element to it, if there isn't, create a new array with the element. If there is no item, carry on the loop:

```js
var a = [
  {id:16, name:"product",productCount:1},
  {id:17, name:"clothes",productCount:1},
]

var b = [
  {id:1, parentId:16, name:"phone"},
  {id:2, parentId:17, name:"coat"},
  {id:3, parentId:16, name:"mac"},
  {id:4, parentId:16, name:"apple"},
]

b.forEach(o => {
  const item = a.find(({id}) => id === o.parentId)
  item && item.children ? item.children.push(o) : item.children = [o]
})
  
console.log(a)
```

A more efficient way to write this would be to construct a map first, instead of calling find on every loop:

```js
var a = [{id:16, name:"product",productCount:1},{id:17, name:"clothes",productCount:1}]
var b = [{id:1, parentId:16, name:"phone"},{id:2, parentId:17, name:"coat"},{id:3, parentId:16, name:"mac"},{id:4, parentId:16, name:"apple"}]

const map = new Map(a.map(({id}, i) => [id, i]))

b.forEach(o => {
  const i = map.get(o.parentId)
  i !== undefined && a[i].children ? a[i].children.push(o) : a[i].children = [o]
})
  
console.log(a)
```

Comment: No problem. If you need any more help, feel free to ask.

Comment: What do you mean? What result and what form?

Comment: The problem has been updated. Could you take a look at it?

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for your answer

Answer (score 1):

We use `reduce` to create a new array.

We construct new objects by taking the current object from array `a` and adding a new key to it. The new key is the result of applying `filter` to array 'b', where we selected the ones that match our current object's id (from array 'a').

```js
var a = [{id:16,name:"product",productCount:1},{id:17,name:"clothes",productCount:1},]
var b = [{id:1,parentId:16,name:"phone"},{id:2,parentId:17,name:"coat"},{id:3,parentId:16,name:"mac"},{id:4,parentId:16,name:"apple"},];

function childToParentMerge(ar1, ar2) {
  return ar1.reduce((a,c) => (a.push({...c, childAs: ar2.filter(o => o.parentId == c.id)}),a),[])
}

console.log(childToParentMerge(a,b))
```

The following is conform with the updated description:

```js
var a = [{id:16,name:"product",productCount:1},{id:17,name:"clothes",productCount:1},]
var b = [{id:1,parentId:16,name:"phone"},{id:2,parentId:17,name:"coat"},{id:3,parentId:16,name:"mac"},{id:4,parentId:16,name:"apple"},];

function childToParentMerge(ar1, ar2) {
  return ar1.reduce((a,c) => (a.push({label: c.name, value: c.id, childAs: 
     ar2.reduce((ac,oc) => 
          (oc.parentId == c.id && ac.push({label: oc.name, value: oc.parentId}),ac),[])
     }),a),[])
}

console.log(childToParentMerge(a,b))
```

Comment: @BaiClassmateXiao I added a second snippet that works with `label` and `value`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and `filter`

- map over array `a`, for each element filter the values form `b` with `parentId` same as `id` of current element
- Build a new object with current element along with the `childAs` property

```js
var a = [{id:16, name:"product",productCount:1},{id:17, name:"clothes",productCount:1}]
var b = [{id:1, parentId:16, name:"phone"},{id:2, parentId:17, name:"coat"},{id:3, parentId:16, name:"mac"},{id:4, parentId:16, name:"apple"}]

let final = a.map(inp => {
  let childs = b.filter(({parentId})=> parentId === inp.id)
  return {...inp,childAs:childs}
})

console.log(Object.values(final))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and push the values to the corresponding parents.

```js
var a = [{ id: 16, name: "product", productCount: 1 }, { id: 17, name: "clothes", productCount: 1 }],
    b = [{ id: 1, parentId: 16, name: "phone" }, { id: 2, parentId: 17, name: "coat" }, { id: 3, parentId: 16, name: "mac" }, { id: 4, parentId: 16, name: "apple" }],
    map = a.reduce((m, o) => m.set(o.id, Object.assign({}, o, { children: [] })), new Map),
    result = [...map.values()];

b.forEach(o => map.get(o.parentId).children.push(o));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could group `b` based on `parentId`. Then `map` the `a` array and get the children from `grouped`

```js
const a=[{id:16,name:"product",productCount:1},{id:17,name:"clothes",productCount:1},],
      b=[{id:1,parentId:16,name:"phone"},{id:2,parentId:17,name:"coat"},{id:3,parentId:16,name:"mac"},{id:4,parentId:16,name:"apple"},];

const grouped = b.reduce((map, o) => 
  map.set(o.parentId, (map.get(o.parentId) || []).concat(o))
, new Map)

const output = a.map(o => ({ ...o, childAs: grouped.get(o.id) || [] }))

console.log(output)
```